# Why do people say Kurt Wagner (a.k.a Nightcrawler) is a prankster?

Tags: marvel, x-men

I've only seen one example, in "Divided We Fall" where Nightcrawler has a prank war with Wolverine but other than that, nothing.

Comment: Who says he is a prankster?